# How to get the clicked view to parent activity from custom list

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom list view with custom array adapter. My problem is while clicking on the edit image I need that related text on my edit text. I searched a lot, but I can't get the solutions.

My code is:

```
public class SimpleAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<Data> implements OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<Data> items;
Context context;
TextView tv1;
ImageView edit;
ImageView delete;

public SimpleAdapter1(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Data> catDesc) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, catDesc);
    this.items = (ArrayList<Data>) catDesc;
    this.context = context;     
    System.out.println(items);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.masterlist, null);
    }
    Data dt = items.get(position);
    if (dt != null) {
        tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mastext1);
        if (tv1 != null) {
            tv1.setText(dt.getDesc());
        }
    }
    });
    tv1.setOnClickListener(this);       
    edit = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.editImage);
    delete = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteImage);
    edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }
    });
    delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    items.get(position).getDesc() + " delete",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return v;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.mastext1:         
        break;  
    }

}
}
```

[image: This is the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your SampleAdapter:

```
private DeleteClickListener mDeleteClickListener;

public void setOnDeleteClickListener(DeleteClickListener deleteClickListener) {
    mDeleteClickListener = deleteClickListener;
}

public static interface DeleteClickListener {
    public void onDelete(int id);
}
```

and then from your activity which `implements` `DeleteClickListener` call this `myAdapter.setOnDeleteClickListener(this);`.
and now in your `getView()` do this:

```
 delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(mDeleteClickListener!=null){
             mDeleteClickListener.onDelete(position);
        }
    }
});
```

PS: Same procedure goes for edit button.

Comment: `adapter.setOnDeleteClickListener(this);` it shows `The method setOnDeleteClickListener(MastersActivity) is undefined for the type ArrayAdapter<Data>` My adapter code is `ArrayAdapter<Data> adapter = new SimpleAdapter1(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.masterlist, catDesc);` is a arrayList.

Comment: As i said please let your `MasterActivity` implement `DeleteClickListener`.

Comment: oh and instead of `ArrayAdapter<Data> adapter = new SimpleAdapter1(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.masterlist, catDesc);` do this `SimpleAdapter1 adapter = new SimpleAdapter1(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.masterlist, catDesc);` and then call `adapter.setOnDeleteClickListener(this);`.